# How can I use DBus to create a client and server without dbus configuration files on recent releases of Ubuntu?

Tags: python3, dbus

I want to use a bridge between a flask webapp and python subprocesses under python3.  I couldn't find a copy paste-able example of a service instantiated without config files for the same.

The reason for wanting to do this is so that I can have multiple threads/processes and use a single Dbus process as a session broker between app instances to hold game state.

All of the trivial Dbus examples I found only included python2.x demos or old versions of whatever mainloop vehicle you prefer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example requires:

`python3-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5, python3-dbus`

Server example:

```
import signal, sys
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import math
import dbus
import dbus.service
from dbus.mainloop.pyqt5 import DBusQtMainLoop

class Server(dbus.service.Object):
  def __init__(self):
    busName = dbus.service.BusName('org.documentroot.Fisticuffs', bus = dbus.SessionBus())
    dbus.service.Object.__init__(self, busName, '/Fisticuffs')
    #Insert subprocesses here...

  @dbus.service.method('org.documentroot.Fisticuffs', in_signature = 's', out_signature = 's')
  def move(self, a): return "Move recieved"
  @dbus.service.method('org.documentroot.Fisticuffs', in_signature = 'dd', out_signature = 'd')
  def add(self, a, b): return a+b

DBusQtMainLoop(set_as_default = True)
app = QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
server = Server()
app.exec_()
```

Client example:

```
import dbus

bus = dbus.SessionBus()
server = bus.get_object('org.documentroot.Fisticuffs', '/Fisticuffs')
print('5 and 10 are:')
print(server.add(5, 10, dbus_interface = 'org.documentroot.Fisticuffs'))
```

Credits:
Adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4938723/486399) to get pyqt5 to listen to <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
and [here](http://www.documentroot.net/en/linux/python-dbus-tutorial) to update a tutorial on getting a dbus-python server to run in the PyQt5 mainloop on python3.

Comment: All I get is `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dbus.mainloop.pyqt5'`